# How do I pass button click event if I am using this.props.children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, children, preact

I have created a react component which is the modal wrapper only. The content is passed by this.props.children. In the content I have a button, clicking it should pass an event to the parent.

Here is the render part of modal wrapper code

```js
<div class="modal-container-backdrop">
            <div class="modal-container-overlay" onClick={this.onOverlayClick}>
                <div class="modal-container-content" style={{padding: this.props.isCloseable ? '30px 20px' : '0px 0px' }} onClick={this.onContentClick} style={{width: this.props.modalWidth ? this.props.modalWidth+'px' : '320px'}}>
                    {this.props.isCloseable ? <div class="modal-container-close-img" onClick={this.onCloseImgClick}></div> : null }
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: the button is defined inside `children`, not the `modal-container-close-img` or `modal-container-content` right? And which click handler do you want to use the catch the children's click event? There are three click handlers in your code

Answer (score 0):

It is not so different just passing a callback handler without using `{this.props.children}`. Am I missing something?

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  handleClick = () => alert("clicked");

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Click</button>
        </Child>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need do it using React.children

```
      {React.Children.map(children, child => React.cloneElement(child, {
        ...this.pros,
        onClick: () => console.log("click")
      }), null)}
```

This a really good post about childrens on React:

https://mxstbr.blog/2017/02/react-children-deepdive/